# Getting objects in dropdown Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, object

I am trying to populate `JSON data` to `HTML Dropdown` and I did it successfuly. 
Now what I want is: 
To get `ID` of selected listitem when I click on it *(id which is coming in JSON not the DOM id)* So I did it like this:

```
$http({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
            'Accept':       'application/json'
        },
        url:    'someURL',
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        var myData1 = JSON.parse(response.data);
        // Preparing data to send to DOM
        var myNames = [];

        $.each(myData1, function(index, value){
            // I can use some real data instead of 'Some static string' but just because of ease. I am passing it hard coded.
            myNames.push({"name": "Some static string",
                          "id":   1});
        })
       /* This is with real data
       $.each(myData1, function(index, value){
        myNames.push({"name": value.stationNameEn,
                      "id":   value.stationNameid});
      })
      */

        $scope.names = JSON.stringify(myNames);
        console.log(myNames);
        })

    .catch(function(error, status, headers, config){
            console.log("Some problem occured: " + JSON.stringify(error)); 
        })


    // Sending data to DOM
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
        $scope.formData.selectedItem = item;
    console.log($scope.formData.selectedName);
    }
```

On my DOM I have:

```
<select class="ion-input-select padding"
        ng-model="formData.selectedName" 
        ng-options="x for x in names"
        ng-change="dropboxitemselected();"
        >
</select>

 selectedName: {{formData.selectedName}}
```

Problem: 
I am getting all results as Objects, when I `JSON.stringify()` it, it splits into individual letter, like:

`r
e
s
u
l
t
s`

What I want is: 
Getting `id` which is coming from `JSON`, when I click on `list item`.

Comment: you don't `JSON.stringify` the `myNames`.. just `$scope.names = myNames` maybe?

Comment: Hello! I agree. It was just for the sake that I try doing it as well. But when I don't use it my list item is having `object` and `object` and `object`. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you guys have any conventional way that, When I click on `dropdown` item of html I get `id` of it _(id not of index, but id of database)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change things like this to achieve which you wanted :

In controller :

change line:

```
 $scope.names = JSON.stringify(myNames); to $scope.names = myNames
```

In the View / DOM :

```
<select class="ion-input-select padding"
        ng-model="formData.selectedName" 
        ng-options="x as x.name for x in names"
        ng-change="dropboxitemselected();"
        >
</select>

 selectedName: {{formData.selectedName.name}}
```

To retrieve Id in your controller :

```
$scope.dropboxitemselected = function () {
        Console.log($scope.formData.selectedName.id);
    }
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thank You very much. Hail *SO Community*

Comment: Just for the sake of learning, How do other people get `ID` _(of db)_ from list item when they click on it. Can you _(anyone)_ please post some links.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of

```
$scope.names = JSON.stringify(myNames);
```

The above code will convert the myNames object into a string. When you provide a string in ng-repeat it iterates over each character and hence, you get each letter. Instead, just use

```
$scope.names = myNames;
```

Comment: Thank You very much @Manas Hemrajani. Indeed your guess was right. It helped 50% to solve my problem.